# This app was built for an older android version and may not work properly

Tags: android, android-10.0

Can disable this warning dialog (This app was built for an older android version and may not work properly) without app upgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning is from the android OS itself, you can not disable it, unfortunately, you have to at least rebuild the app with a higher target version.

Comment: I am afraid no.